# How to get my content grouping shown in python

Tags: python-2.7

code below sends command to generate secret then checks to ensure that no secret is the same. Towards the end of my code (I will state later) I'm not sure why my prior groupings are now stating that object has no attribute group. I grouped it right so yeah Any ideas...Here's the code I have thus far:

```
def PairingSecret(self):
    # Enter submenu--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ser = self.portMan
    result = Test.TestResult.NOTRUN
    if not ser.EnterSubmenu('siteprot'):
        return Test.TestResult.NORESPONSE

    # Send secret Cmd
    ser.SendCmd("modal 0")
    log = ser.SendCmd("secret")

    # Verifying active and secret == 0
    if ser.DoesContain(log, "active = 0" and "secret: 0") == False:
        self.log.WriteError("Incorrect value for ACTIVE and SECRET key")
        result = Test.TestResult.FAIL

    else:
        result = Test.TestResult.PASS

    #Send Cmd
    ser.SendCmd("modal 1")
    log = ser.SendCmd("secret")

    # verifying active == 1 and secret is a four digit
    sec_value = re.search('(\d{4,4})$', log [1])

    if ser.DoesContain(log, "active = 1") == False:
          self.log.WriteError("Incorrect value for Active key")
          result = Test.TestResult.FAIL

    else:
        result = Test.TestResult.PASS

    # Send Cmd then check secret
    ser.SendCmd("modal 0")
    ser.SendCmd("modal 1")
    log = ser.SendCmd("secret")

    # verifying active == 1 and secret is a four digit value != first secret
    sec_value2 = re.search('(\d{1,4})$',log [1])

    if sec_value2:
        secret = int(sec_value.group(1))
        secret2 = int(sec_value2.group(1))

        if secret == secret2:
            result = Test.TestResult.FAIL

    else:
        result = Test.TestResult.PASS

    # Send mod 0 command
    ser.SendCmd("modal 0")
    log = ser.SendCmd("secret")

    if ser.DoesContain(log,"active = 0" and "secret: 0") == False:
        self.log.WriteError("Incorrect value for ACTIVE and SECRET key\r\n")
        result = Test.TestResult.FAIL

    else:
        result = Test.TestResult.PASS

    # Send gensec and extract four digit value
    log = ser.SendCmd("gensec")
    gen_secret = re.search('(\d{4,4})$', log [1])
```

## --------------------THIS IS WHERE MY GROUPING FOR SECRET AND SECRET2 SHOWS NO ATTRIBUTES----------

```
    # Verify gen_secret != with first two modal 1 command secret
    if gen_secret:
        gen_sec = int(gen_secret.group(1))
        secret = int(sec_value.group(1))
        secret2 = int(sec_value2.group(1))

        if gen_sec == secret or secret2:
            result = Test.TestResult.FAIL

    else:
        result = Test.TestResult.PASS

    # Exit Submenu
    if not ser.ExitSubmenu():
        return Test.TestResult.NORESPONSE

    return result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is probably wrong:

```
    if gen_sec == secret or secret2:
```

and should be:

```
    if gen_sec == secret or gen_sec == secret2:
```

or

```
    if gen_sec in [secret, secret2]:
```